# Error clean and build - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Tags: java

El proyecto me compila y me funciona perfecto sólo que al realizar un **CLEAN AND BUILD** del mismo, me sale el siguiente error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at interfaz.Ficha_tecnica_alquiler.jComboBox_bastidorItemStateChanged(Ficha_tecnica_alquiler.java:238)
    at interfaz.Ficha_tecnica_alquiler.access$000(Ficha_tecnica_alquiler.java:13)
    at interfaz.Ficha_tecnica_alquiler$1.itemStateChanged(Ficha_tecnica_alquiler.java:125)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1223)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1280)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1330)
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
```

Os dejo el código de las clases/métodos aunque ya os digo que todo funciona OK.

```
private void jComboBox_bastidorItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                    
        //Recogemos en la variable "bastidor" el valor seleccionado en el combobox con el método "getSelectedItem()".
        String bastidor = (String) jComboBox_bastidor.getSelectedItem();
        //Guardamos en un objecto "v" los datos del bastidor gracias a la función "Conexiones.datos_de_un_bastidor_alquiler(bastidor);".
        Object[] v = Conexiones.datos_de_un_bastidor_alquiler(bastidor);
        //Otorgamos a los campos jTextField los valores recogidos en el "Object[] v".
        textfield_marca.setText(String.valueOf(v[0]));
        textfield_modelo.setText(String.valueOf(v[1]));
        textfield_matricula.setText(String.valueOf(v[2]));
        textfield_disponible.setText(String.valueOf(v[3]));

        //Creamos un objecto bidimensional llamado "tabla" donde guardamos los datos de la función "Conexiones.clientes_alquilado_vehiculo(bastidor);".
        Object[][] tabla = Conexiones.clientes_alquilado_vehiculo(bastidor);
        //Fila de los títulos de la tabla.
        String[] titulos = {"NOMBRE", "DNI", "FECHA ALQUILER", "FECHA DE ENTREGA", "ESTADO DEVOLUCION"};
        //Agregamos al objeto de tipo DefaultTableModel "dtm" los parámetros necesarios.
        dtm = new DefaultTableModel(tabla, titulos);
        //Añadimos los datos del "dtm" a la tabla "table_alquiler".
        table_alquiler.setModel(dtm);
        //tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(model.findColumn("NombreColumna")).setPreferredWidth(tamaño);
        table_alquiler.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(180); //Nombre
        table_alquiler.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(180); //DNI
        table_alquiler.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(240); //Fecha de alquilado
        table_alquiler.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(280); //Fecha de entrega real
        table_alquiler.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(300); //Estado devolucion
    }    

public static Object[] datos_de_un_bastidor_alquiler(String bastidor) {
        //Creamos un objeto "v" de 4 valores: marca, modelo, matricula, disponible.
        Object[] v = new Object[4];
        String bd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todos los datos del vehiculo_alquiler de un bastidor.
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_de_un_bastidor = "SELECT v.*, va.fecha_v_alquiler, va.disponible, m.nombre FROM vehiculos AS v, vehiculos_alquiler AS va, marca AS m "
                    + "WHERE v.bastidor='" + bastidor + "' AND v.bastidor=va.bastidor AND v.marca=m.ID;";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_de_un_bastidor);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA DATOS: Datos de un bastidor en concreto.\n");
            rs.next();
            String marca = rs.getString("nombre");
            String modelo = rs.getString("modelo");
            String matricula = rs.getString("matricula");
            int disponible = rs.getInt("disponible");
            v[0] = marca;
            v[1] = modelo;
            v[2] = matricula;
            v[3] = disponible;
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Ese es un error de ejecución. No veo como un `clean and build` te pueda dar este error.

Comment: Al cerrar el Netbeans y volverle a abrir ese error desapareció de la nada...